# How to block sending POST requests from IIS?

Tags: iis-8

I need to block all non-GET requests to a REST API from a web application hosted in an IIS 8.5, just for a few days. My idea is to while we perform some migration tasks, the users will not be able to add, modify or delete any information in the system where we store all the data. Our plan is to block the user from the interface, but also we want to block all POST, PUT and DELETE exiting calls to the API domain.

Is it possible to block sending these headers, while we allow the GETs, from IIS or web.config level?

Comment: From MS documents: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/configure-request-filtering-in-iis - search for VERBS

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use request filtering to allow only GET requests and block all other types of HTTP methods  and allow others:

web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <verbs allowUnlisted="false">
        <add verb="GET" allowed="true"/> 
      </verbs>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Is this going to block POSTs coming into the web application or exiting?

Comment: @Bargant  IIS Request Filtering helps prevent potentially harmful requests from being processed by web applications on the server. If you would like to prevent your web application from sending POST requests to another service or application, that would be handled within the application's code or configuration, not through IIS Request Filtering.